# У меня есть код скулайт и когда я запускаю бота выходит ошибка помогите Сам код:

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3, discord.py

Выходит ошибка с дб Sqlite3. Вот код в котором возникает ошибка:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name TEXT, id INT, cash BIGINT, prem INT, bank BIGINT, server_id INT, case_money INT)""")
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (role_id INT, id INT, cost BIGINT)""")

for guild in bot.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
            cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO users VALUES ("{str(member).replace("'", "")}", {member.id}, 0, 0, 0, {guild.id}, 1)""")
        else:
            pass

connection.commit()
print('bot connected')
```

Ошибка:

```
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO users VALUES ("{str(member).replace("'", "")}", {member.id}, 0, 0, 0, {guild.id}, 1)""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Aila": syntax error
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что часто появляющиеся слова "у меня есть код" подразумевают также: "его написал кто-то другой, как он работает, мне неизвестно"?

Comment: Нет. Код хорошо работал, хотел изменить параметры, потом вернул и он перестал работать

Comment: тогда 3 вопроса подтолкнуть к решению (я его не знаю, но в вопросе начальном эта информация будет полезна): 1) что такое near "Aila", 2) какой именно мелкий кусочек это обрабатывает,  и 3) Что именно должно быть результатом обработки? (написать до символа) (И под "как" я имел в виду логику работы, а не "хорошо" или "плохо")

Comment: 1. Наверно имя человека, который бот не может добавить в дб
2.Запуск бота и бд
3.Если бот работает "хорошо" он должен выдать bot connected, плохо, когда эта ошибка выходит

И от меня вопрос:
Вас должно интересовать кто сделал код и знаю ли как он работает?

Comment: 1) Это ресурс для помощи тем, в основном, кто сам что-то делает и задает вопросы. Как видите, кроме меня вообще никто не отозвался. Это же бесплатная помощь. А мне и просто интересно знать, правильно ли я понял "у меня есть код" и особо это важно из-за следующего пункта.  2) Я не уверен, может ли кто-либо вообще ответить на вопрос, заданный в такой форме. Я, например, не могу, так как мне надо бы знать, где эта near "Aila" в коде проверяется, и что ожидается (это мои вопросы 2 и 3). 90%, что если вы на вопросы 2 и 3 ответите, то и сами найдете, в чем дело. Успеха! Надеюсь, кто-то поможет.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо! Я уже сам разобрался. Alia заменил значением m которого очень много в интеренете и нашёл ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Ну, вот, я же говорил:-)

Comment: Ещё раз вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO users VALUES ("{str(member).replace("'", "")}", {member.id}, 0, 0, 0, {guild.id}, 1)"""). Он написан полностью неправильно. Правильный код снизу:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name TEXT, id INT, cash BIGINT, prem TEXT, bank BIGINT, server_id INT, case_money INT)""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (role_id INT, id INT, cost BIGINT)""")

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?", ( member.id, )):
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, 0, 0, 0, ?, 1)", ( str(member), member.id, guild.id ) )
        else:
            pass

connection.commit()
print('bot connected')
```

Comment: лучше еще текстом написать над кодом в ответе, что именно изменено